# Impossible to get about 70% of height of Likelihood when I project the edge 1 sigma joint distribution on the 1D Likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, covariance, likelihood, joint-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

This post has been initially asked on maths.exchange but I didn't get any help, so I try to transfer it on this forum hoping someone could help me (I am going to delete the post on maths.exchange to not have a duplicated post).

I have currently an issue with what my teacher said about the height at which the projection of 1 sigma edges in 2D contour should intersect the associated Likelihood.

Here a figure to illustrate my issue :

[image: Issue of intersection on the likelihood]

At bottom left is represented the joint distribution (shaded blue = contours at 2 sigma (95% C.L) and classic blue = contours at 1 sigma (68% C.L) of the 2 parameters considered (w0 and wa).
On the top is represented the normalized Likelihood of w0 parameter.

In all contours (with all triplot representing other parameters) and in all tripltot of thesis documents I have seen, the projection from the edge of 1 sigma contours on the likelihood intersects the likelihood at a height relatively low (on my scheme, roughly at 25%-30%, at first sight, of the maximum height of the likelihood).

**However, my teacher tells me that Likelihood should be intersected by the 1 sigma edge of joint distribution at roughly 70% of the maximum height of Likelihood (green bar and text on my figure)**

**For this, he justifies like this :**

Concerning $\Delta \chi^{2}$, distribution function is a $\chi^2$ law with 2 freedom degrees ; pdf is written as :

$f(\Delta\chi^{2})=\dfrac{1}{2} e^{-\dfrac{\Delta\chi^{2}}{2}}$

So for a fixed confidence level $CL$, we have :

$ 1-CL=\int_{\Delta\chi^{2}_{CL}}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{2}e^{-\dfrac{\Delta\chi^{2}}{2}}\text{d}\chi^{2}$

$=e^{-\dfrac{\Delta\chi_{CL}^{2}}{2}}$

and taking $CL=0.68$, we get :

$\Delta \chi ^{2}_{CL}=-2\ln(1-CL)$

$\Delta \chi^{2}_{CL}=2.28$

And Finally, he concludes by saying that Maximum of Likelihood shoud fall from about 30% , i.e :

$e^{-\dfrac{(2.3)^2}{2}} = 0.31$

**So I don't know why I get a falling of about 70% ~ (1-0.31) and not only of 31% ~ 0.3 like my teacher says on my figure (red line on my figure above).**

If anyone could explain me this issue. I insist that I read different thesis in a context of cosmology **and all likelihood for all parameters are intersected at a height equal roughly to 30% of the maximum height**, **so this would be a revolution (in terms of wrong results) if my teacher is right. (or maybe my likelihood is not really normalized ? ).**

So finally, who is right ?

Any help is welcome.

**UPDATE 1:** Here an illustration of the issue :

[image: Height of intersection doesn't occur at 70% of height max of Likelihood]

**UPDATE 2** : reading the documentation, it may be a problem of a factor for the computation of ellipses. Below the explanations and equations that are used in cosmicfish :

Once we compute a Fisher matrix it might be useful to plot the marginalized joint posterior probability of two parameters $\left(\theta_{i}, \theta_{j}\right),$ assuming that it is Gaussian, starting from the Fisher matrix. This helps shedding light on the possible degeneracy between two parameters and how this degeneracy changes or breaks when considering different experiments. Let us denote:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma_{i}^{2} &=\left(F^{-1}\right)_{i i} \\
\sigma_{j}^{2} &=\left(F^{-1}\right)_{j j} \\
\sigma_{i j}^{2} &=\left(F^{-1}\right)_{i j}
\end{aligned}
$$
we can immediately compute:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a &=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_{i}^{2}+\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\left(\sigma_{i}^{2}-\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{2}+\sigma_{i j}^{4}}} \\
b &=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sigma_{i}^{2}+\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\left(\sigma_{i}^{2}-\sigma_{j}^{2}\right)^{2}+\sigma_{i j}^{4}}} \\
\phi_{0} &=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{atan}\left(\frac{2 \sigma_{i j}^{2}}{\sigma_{i}^{2}-\sigma_{j}^{2}}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
and we can write the parametric form of the Fisher ellipse in the $\theta_{i}, \theta_{j}$ plane as:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\theta_{i}=\alpha\left(a \cos (\phi) \cos \left(\phi_{0}\right)-b \sin (\phi) \sin \left(\phi_{0}\right)\right)+\theta_{i}^{0} \\
\theta_{j}=\alpha\left(a \cos (\phi) \sin \left(\phi_{0}\right)+b \sin (\phi) \cos \left(\phi_{0}\right)\right)+\theta_{j}^{0} \quad \forall \phi \in[0,2 \pi]
\end{array}
$$
where $\left(\theta_{i}^{0}, \theta_{j}^{0}\right)$ is the value of the fiducial parameters and $\alpha$ is a coefficient encoding the confidence level of the ellipse and is given by $\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ Erfinv (C.L.) where Erfinv denotes the inverse Error function and C.L. is the desired confidence level $0 \leq \mathrm{C.L.} \leq 1$

Where does this factor $\sqrt{2}$ in the equation $$\alpha=\sqrt{2}$ Erfinv (C.L.) come from ? Maybe this is the cause of my issue ?

By the way, I don't even know what `Erfinv` corresponds to ?

If someone could explain me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Could you link and reference the papers you allude too?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen . Thanks for your interest, I didn't think that one day, someone would answer me. You can see an example on the following thesis http://thesesups.ups-tlse.fr/4347/1/2018TOU30212.pdf page 341/436.  I put the illustration in **UPDATE 1**. As you can see, the projection of 1.CL red contour on the associted red likelihood is not located at 70% of the maximal height of the Gaussian. the intersection occurs roughly at 0.3 = 30% of the max height.

Comment: From this, I have used another Python library called **cosmicfish** https://cosmicfish.github.io/documentation/CosmicFishPyLib/index.html. I get better results at the level of the height of the intersection but still not 0.7 (I reach it between 0.5 and 0.6) but not 0.7 as expected. If you had some idea to suggest, I would be glad that you tell me it. Best regards

Comment: You can see the documentation of cosmicfish here : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06268.pdf . I have got to look for into this to find the factor which puts the mess.